# How to properly install dj-stripe into a Django project?

Tags: django, heroku, stripe-payments

I want to deploy dj-stripe for my payment processing on heroku.

1) I have created the project payments

2) I have installed dj-stripe and in INSTALLED_APPS, I have included 'djstripe'.

3) Next, I have included the urlpattern

```
 url(r'^stripe/', include('djstripe.urls', namespace="djstripe")),
```

4) Now, when I go to `localhost:5000/stripe/`, it redirects to `localhost:5000/accounts/login/?next=/stripe/` and thow this error on my face

```
Using the URLconf defined in payment.urls, Django tried these URL       patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^stripe/
The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

**EDIT:**

As per the docs, I have added these in my project's settings.py

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY", "<your publishable key>")
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY", "<your secret key>")
and

DJSTRIPE_PLANS = {
    "monthly": {
        "stripe_plan_id": "pro-monthly",
        "name": "Web App Pro ($25/month)",
        "description": "The monthly subscription plan to WebApp",
        "price": 2500,  # $25.00
        "currency": "usd",
        "interval": "month"
    },
    "yearly": {
        "stripe_plan_id": "pro-yearly",
        "name": "Web App Pro ($199/year)",
        "description": "The annual subscription plan to WebApp",
        "price": 19900,  # $199.00
        "currency": "usd",
        "interval": "year"
    }
}
```

And finally I have run these commands

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py djstripe_init_customers
python manage.py djstripe_init_plans
```

Comment: looks like djstripe uses LoginRequiredMixin on its views, meaning it requires an active session in order to show some of all of its views. since you are not logged in and don't have a session, it tries to redirect you to the login url ("accounts/login") which you didn't handle and getting url not found on it.

Comment: Yes, they use LoginRequiredMixin class. Could you please elaborate on how I should fix this?

Comment: well the LoginRequiredMixin is a mixin you can add to views that basically say "you can't watch this view unless you are logged in!". so if djstripe uses it it means they don't want their views to be accessed from anonymous user. the solution? to integrate users / login mechanism in order to satisfy this demand. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/

Comment: PS you should probably edit your question title. its too general.

Answer (score 0):

Per the dj-stripe [docs](http://dj-stripe.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuration), add to your **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^payments/', include('djstripe.urls', namespace="djstripe")),
```

Add to your config:

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY", "<your publishable key>")
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY", "<your secret key>")
```

and

```
DJSTRIPE_PLANS = {
    "monthly": {
        "stripe_plan_id": "pro-monthly",
        "name": "Web App Pro ($25/month)",
        "description": "The monthly subscription plan to WebApp",
        "price": 2500,  # $25.00
        "currency": "usd",
        "interval": "month"
    },
    "yearly": {
        "stripe_plan_id": "pro-yearly",
        "name": "Web App Pro ($199/year)",
        "description": "The annual subscription plan to WebApp",
        "price": 19900,  # $199.00
        "currency": "usd",
        "interval": "year"
    }
}
```

Then run the commands

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py djstripe_init_customers
python manage.py djstripe_init_plans
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, ... I did this already as per the docs!

Comment: Oh well, hmm. It looks like the comment by Ness would be the next best place to follow up on.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue!

The problem was I had not created the superuser account yet. I included the admin package and created the superuser account. That solved the issue :)